# Creating ActionLinks while still preserving the original Uri/route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with a default Index action, as well as many other actions each rendering their own view.

When an action method calls another action, the Uri in the browser is something like

http://localhost/Home/Events/20100120/Sydney

How would I create an Action Link in one of my templates like this for example, and still preserve the other route values?
http://localhost/Home/Events/20100120/Sydney/10PM

If I do this, I lose all the other route values in the Uri.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View 10PM times", "Events", "Home", new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"time", "10PM"} })%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route data is automatically preserved. Suppose that you have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "foo/{token1}/{token2}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Action1", token1 = "", token2 = "" }
);
```

Now you request `/foo/t1/t2/Action1` and inside the view you write a link to `Action2`:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Action2", "Action2")%>
```

The following url will be generated: `/foo/t1/t2/Action2`. Route values are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Html.RouteLink() like so:

```
<%
    var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    routeData.Add("time", "10PM");
%>
<%=Html.RouteLink("View 10PM times", routeData) %>
```